# Download web page with images and stylesheets and (optionally) E-mailing it

Tags: php, html, css, screen-scraping

I need to make snapshots of web pages programmatically using PHP and get them into a HTML E-Mail.

I tried `wget --page-requisites`. It downloads everything all right, but it doesn't change the HTML page's source code to point to the downloaded files rather than the on-line originals. Also, that HTML is of course a long way from being displayed properly in a HTML E-Mail.

I am interested to know whether there are ready-made solutions for this. I would already be happy with a solution that takes a HTML snapshot and changes the HTML accordingly. Being able to E-Mail it would be the icing on the cake.

I control the web pages being snapshot, so I have the possibility to adjust the content to optimize the results.

My server-side platform is PHP but with very liberal settings, I can execute things like wget and Perl scripts from within PHP. I do however not have root access and can not install additional packages or programs.

The task is to make a snapshot of a product page each time somebody places an order, so there is documentation about what the page looked like at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wget has a `-k` (`--convert-links`) option, which will convert both links and references to embedded content (like images). See e.g. [wget advanced use](http://gnu.huihoo.org/wget-1.8.1/html_chapter/wget_toc.html#TOC32) (also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget#Advanced_usage)).

For the email-part of your question - I'm sure you can use one of the existing libraries. For example, PHP has some PEAR package (do no remember the exact name) to handle HTML emails; I'm pretty sure both Perl and Python have something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you try to do a website mirroring using wget. The simple solution is to use [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) which is a simple command-line tool. It's very powerful and configurable, try it!
The httrack website presents a GUI, but you don't need it, all is possible from the command-line (or from PHP).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not install additional programs on the server (it's a Linux webserver). But if anybody could point me towards a standard Linux tool that can do the same as httrack, this might help me.

Comment: Even if you compile httrack in your directory ? Or you could simply deploy httrack with your php app (in a subdirectory).