# file_get_contents full code with images, scripts

Tags: php, html, stream, file-get-contents

Is there any way to get full source code with images,scripts who is used in page... file_get_contents give only elements without images,script... What I need is when catch some URL (file_get_contents / echo $URL ) to render page like iframe doing. (with images,scripts etc) Is this possible and is there any funcion for that...

```
<?php

$URL='www.example.com';
$data= file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: No builtin for that. Easier with external tools. For example `wget --mirror` can also download assets and convert references into local paths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download web page with images and stylesheets and (optionally) E-mailing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815592/download-web-page-with-images-and-stylesheets-and-optionally-e-mailing-it)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928509/php-mirror-a-webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there exists a built in function for that. But you can write it, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

THE SOLUTION IS SO EASY:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;

echo $data;


?>
```